# Replace object value without replacing reference

Tags: javascript, object, reference

How can you update an entire object, say:

```
var x = {a:1}
function modify(obj) {
  obj = {b:2}
}
modify(x)
console.log(x) // {a:1}
```

But maintain the reference? I want the object to be modified outside the function.

My specific case is using `lodash.pick` inside my function:

```
if (whitelist) {
  obj = _.pick(obj, whitelist)
}
```

I can't seem to find a `pick` function that modifies the object. Is there a way to do this or do I need to start returning copies of the object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`delete` everything from the old object, and then add new properties, key-by-key:

```js
function modify(obj, newObj) {

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    delete obj[key];
  });

  Object.keys(newObj).forEach(function(key) {
    obj[key] = newObj[key];
  });
  
}

var x = {a:1}
modify(x, {b:42})
document.write(JSON.stringify(x));
```

If you're wondering whether it's a good idea in general, the answer is no. Construct a new object, return it from the function and assign - this is a much preferred way.

Comment: I ended up using lodash `_.cloneDeep` and returning a new object, but this would be the best solution to the question. And agreed, this is horrible practise.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on why this is so horrible? My scenario is that I have a large array of objects and I'm using a supporting "reference object" to access them by their ID's instead of having to loop through the array. I.e `modify(referenceObject[objectId], updatedObject);`

Comment: "Construct a new object, return it from the function and assign - this is a much preferred way" ---- I'd like to see you try that on a promise-based function

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this (not exactly what you want) if you wrap your object and change the modify function like this,

```
var wrapper = {};
wrapper.x = {a:1};
function modify(obj, key) {
    obj[key] = {b:2};
}
modify(wrapper, 'x');
console.log(wrapper.x); // {b:2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Method to deep update the values of the source object from new object without changing source  object reference
 *
 * @export
 * @param {*} sourceObj
 * @param {*} newObj
 */
export function updateObjKeepingRef(sourceObj: any, newObj: any): void {
  Object.keys(newObj).forEach(key => {
    // if value is object and instance is not Date
    if (newObj[key] && typeof newObj[key] === 'object' && sourceObj[key] && !(newObj[key] instanceof Date)) {
      updateObjKeepingRef(sourceObj[key], newObj[key]);
    } else {
      // updating properties
      sourceObj[key] = newObj[key];
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Why does modify not edit the object referred to by obj?**

Because inside **modify** when you write:

```
obj = {b:2}
```

Note that **obj** is a local variable to the function call of **modify**. A new object `{b:2}` is created, and the local variable **obj** now refers to this new object. Recall that the variable x still refers to the `{a:1}` object.

If **x** is a global variable AND if there is no local variable inside the function by the name, then you can do:

```
var x = {a:1};
function modify() {
  x = {b:2}
}
modify();
console.log(x) // {b:2}
```

---

**Why does the above code work?**

When you call **modify()**, it tries to see if it has a local variable x, since it could not find one, it looks up in the scope chain. The next scope to look for this function call is the global scope, and sure enough, there we have a **x** variable. Hence this global variable **x**'s value is set now.

Comment: Ideally the function modifies the passed-in variable. It looks like I'm going to have to return the object instead of just modify it.

Comment: But if you use "obj.a = 3" instead of "obj = {b:2}" in the function modify, the x's value will be changed.. How do you explain that?

Comment: @plbsam: That's because when you write obj.a = 3, Javascript first does a lookup for the property a in obj. When you called the function modify(x), the local variable obj of the function modify, got set to x, so obj is pointing to the the same object that x points to. Thus when you write obj.a = 3; , it sets the a property of the same object pointed to by x. Make sense?

Comment: @Garrett: Yes, I personally recommend returning the object, as the function I wrote up is so messy, and misleading to the reader. I wrote just for academic purposes of explaining. Returning an object is much kinder on the person who reads/maintains your code.

Comment: @Aravind got it... x is a reference and a copy of x is passed as obj. When modifying, it modifies the same object. When assigning a new object, the reference of the new object is assigned to obj. x doesn't change... Thanks..

Answer (score -2):

I was having this issue. After some research, I opted to convert objectTwo to a JSON string, and then replace objectOne with the parsed version. In other words:

```
var mObjectOne = { ExampleProperty: 10 };
var mObjectTwo = { ExampleProperty: 15 };

// I wanted mObjectOne to hold the same data as mObjectTwo, but keep a separate reference
var mObjectTwoAsJSON = JSON.stringify(mObjectTwo);
mObjectOne = JSON.parse(mObjectTwoAsJSON);

// Now the references are still different, as desired, but the object data has been updated.
```

Thanks,

Comment: That references are different which is not what was asked by the OP

Answer (score -3):

```
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newObj))
```

Comment: please add more context/explanation to your answer

Comment: I am not sure if it will not create a new reference. please elaborate your answer

Comment: I am sure, it will.